# How do I post my blobs into different rows on the same id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-upload

My table:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `img1` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  `img2` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  `ext1` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `ext2` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

I want to work it like…

```
INSERT INTO table
SET img1='$img1', ext1='$ext1', img2='$img2', ext2='$ext2'
WHERE id='$id';
```

**Here is the example** (sorry, dont have rep. for direct image input.): 
This is how it does **right now** ------> https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6jxy.png 
This is how **I want it to work like** -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Bsv.png

But I can't get that working. So far I've saved both of them - but in different ID's. I think, if my id's are fixed, it's gonna post properly.  My '**id**' is **primary key**.
That's my code:

$table = "mytable";

```
if(isset($_FILES['image1'])){
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']));
  $errors=array();
  $file_name1= $_FILES['image1']['name'];
  $file_size=$_FILES['image1']['size'];
  $file_tmp1=$_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image1']['type']; 

  // file type is ok?
  $file_ext1=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image1']['name'])));
  $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png"); 
  if(in_array($file_ext1,$extensions )=== false){
   $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file."; 
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
  $errors[]='File size up to 2 MB';
  }
  if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp1,"uploads/".$file_name1);
    $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table SET id='$id', ext1='$file_ext1', img1='$file_tmp1'");
  }else{
    print_r($errors);
  }
}

if(isset($_FILES['image2'])){
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']));
  $errors=array();
  $file_name2= $_FILES['image2']['name'];
  $file_size=$_FILES['image2']['size'];
  $file_tmp2=$_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image2']['type']; 

  // file type is ok?
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image2']['name'])));
  $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png"); 
  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
   $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file."; 
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
  $errors[]='File size up to 2 MB';
  }
  if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp2,"uploads/".$file_name2);
    $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table SET id='$id', ext2='$file_ext', img2='$file_tmp2'");
  }else{
    print_r($errors);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide details of your table.

Comment: Are you trying to link images to each other? if so look at 'many-to-many' relationships. How are you calculating 'id', which is not a good name, as people expect 'id' to be an 'integer, auto-incrementing' value used as a primary key. Is your '$id' a text field calculated from the other columns in your 'insert'?

Comment: Yes, you need to lookup what `many to many` and `one to many` relationships are.

Comment: I'm coding a post form, which contains 2 images to be uploaded, means: name, surname <...> img1, img2. My $id is the id of post, so I can select exact images for the exact post from whole database to view. That's my vision.

Comment: I suggest you have a table that looks like: 'post-id', 'image_id'  which allows you to 'search' for any 'images' that relate to the 'post-id'. Where 'post-id' is your '$id'.  That way everything works fine.

Comment: Nothing special, just varchars for some fill up inputs, a varchar select for category, int for id and blobs for images. :) I will try your suggestion when I'm able to. To be clear, I need to create a separate table with fields image_id and image_name and then -> table_post => post_id, image_id, also table_image => image_id, image_name?

Comment: Fill in: name, surname, img1, img2., Select: name, surname, img1, img2. I'm doing it to show the exact information that needs to be shown.  Like if you post a form on id 17, you want the info to be selected from id 17, not any other, right? That's my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the field `id` a `primary key` or `unique`?

Usually an `ID` field in arable should have a unique field per row, unless ofcourse it is a `foreign key` that references another table's primary key.

It's not good database design to not have your `ID` field not indexed and not unique.
Additionally, you need to add additional information about the problem your trying to solve and what exactly the `ID` field represents.

The quickest hack would be to remove the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY ID INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE t DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

However, this isn't recommended database design.

Comment: Yes, my 'id' field is a primary key.

Comment: Thus - you asked your database, **not** to accept more than one single record for one particular id… You will need an additional table to store your data.

Comment: You could keep the table if your `image` table is referencing another table in which case you need to have 2 IDs. Example, if each customer stores images and there are two tables (`customer`, `image`). You would have an `id` as primary key in `image` table, and a `cust_id` foreign key in `image` table referencing `customer.id`. The `image.cust_id` would be the ID that is repeating and the same for multiple rows.

Comment: your suggestion was the closest, as ive tested it already, thanks for the solution